# window.parent.$() doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, browser

I don't understand my snippet below, it works perfectly in chrome (not tested in ff yet) but it has error in IE stating "Invalid argument", Is there any way we can work around this problem?

```
window.parent.$('#tdDealItem').append($wrap);
```

Comment: Was `$wrap` created with `window.parent.$()` or with the local `$()`?

Comment: Try just parent.$('#tdDealItem').append($wrap); Also, is the content of the iframe on the same domain as the parent? IE has some strict permission rules so you may be encountering one of those.

Comment: yeah, the content of the iframe is within same domain as the parent.

Comment: Frederic Hamidi - I think I need to thank you for you have given me clue.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried taking out the 'window' part and just using `parent.$('#tdDealItem').append($wrap);`

Comment: yes, i tried, and i also tried it this way $('#tdDealItem', parent.document).append($wrap); but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(w.document.body).$('#tdDealItem').append($wrap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with IE-embedded-in-Silverlight in the form of Silverlight's WebBrowser control.

The fix was a bit off the odd, and I'm not sure I understand *why*, however, taking my solution and applying it to yours, it's just a case of putting `parent.jQuery` into it's own variable, i.e.:

```
var parentjq = parent.jQuery;
parentjq("#tdDealItem").append($wrap);
```

For some reason, IE-in-SL doesn't like the syntax `parent.jQuery(...).`, giving me the "Object doesn't support this property of method 'jQuery'".

It's worth noting that this only happened in IE-in-SL: IE running in IE7 browser mode with IE7 strict didn't exhibit the same problem. However YMMV.

For the curious (and completeness), I had the problem/error message with:

```
var fldid = parent.$("body").data("dateFieldId");
```

But after splitting into:

```
var parentjq = parent.jQuery;
var fldid = parentjq("body").data("dateFieldId");
```

the error went away and I was getting the right results.